# deliver_later with no retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rails-activejob

How do I disable retries with activeMailer and `deliver_later`?

I recently ran across an issue where one of my mailer methods was failing silently due to a syntax error in a view.  We were using `deliver_later` to send messages

When it was finally discovered and fixed, all the old messages that had been failing were re-attempted and then delivered.  These were time-sensitive messages and should not have been retried.

I can not seem to find any way to do something like `.deliver_later(retry: false)`  Would using `deliver_now` solve this problem?

I am using delayed_job as my message queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveJob does not touch the retry settings of the adapters (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb). The only way you can get that if you completely disable the retry mechanism in DJ (`Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 4`)

Comment: Thanks.  That's disappointing, it is not something I'd want to change on such a global level.

Comment: If you use Delayed Job, you can do this `Delayed::Job.enqueue(job, :attempts => 1)`